# Words to describe a young adult or teen who behaves recklessly and won't listen to advice from older people

Tags: expressions

I'm looking for a word (formal, informal, or even slang) to describe *a young person who  behave recklessly, like to mess around and often get into trouble with people, don't listen to advice from older people, and has shallow thinking*.

People in my country have a word which can be translated into "bullheaded kid" but I find it a bit weird so I want to find a proper word for it.

Comment: Apart from bull-headed, mule-headed and pig-headed also work in English. See *mulish*. However, they don't quite fit the description of "a young person who behaves recklessly, ...".

Comment: I can't help thinking that the answer is "everyone who is now my age, 40 years ago."

Comment: @Kris Thank you for your answer. Maybe some words in my language just can't be translated into English without losing some essence

Comment: There probably is a word, just that I can't come up with something right now.

Comment: How about *teenager*?

Answer (score 1):

**Troublemaker** - someone who intentionally causes problems for other people, especially people who are in a position of power or authority:

> *He is a troublemaker with a rough and careless manner.*
>
> *He is a troublemaker at times, but he mostly agrees that his sister is
>   the weird one.*

Source: [the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/troublemaker)

A synonym for *troublemaker* is **mischief-maker**:

If you say that someone is a mischief-maker, you are criticizing them for saying or doing things which are intended to cause trouble between people ([the Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/mischief-maker)):

> *The letter had come from an unknown mischief-maker.*
>
> *The chief among his playmates, he became the mischief-maker of the
>   place.*

Depending on the context, "[**problem child**](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=problem%20child)" may also be used to describe any child (as well as an employee, sibling, or friend) that is constantly getting into trouble but you are somewhat obligated to care for or help:

> *You know, if you want people to stop treating you like a problem
>   child, stop causing problems.*
>
> *She's been a problem child since puberty.*

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, Enguroo. Can you think of some slangs for it?

Comment: @windrider9268 I'd say that a troublemaker may be a pain in the butt (https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/a-pain-in-the-arse). Not because they are young and get into trouble but because they tend to be annoying.

Comment: Thanks again. So I guess there's not really any word that also mean young and likely to get into trouble?

Comment: @windrider9268 Consider "problem child"... I've added some info about it to my answer. To be honest, there may be more words and phrases to describe such a kid but a lot depends on the context and what exactly you want to emphasize. Thus, "troublemaker" is the one who gets into trouble but they may or may not be a child. "Mischief-maker" may be more associated with kids because of the meaning of the word "mischief", but again, it depends on what you mean by mischief and what trouble they've got into. And, finally, a problem child may be a kid as well as an adult. Context is everything.

Comment: I'm surprised nobody suggested "typical teenager".

Comment: @Enguroo I think problem child is a good answer. What I want to emphasize is that person is a young adult (20 to 29) but still behaves like a child and act recklessly sometimes or most of the time.  My cousin is like that, he's 25 but he still lives with his parents and doesn't work, he's easily angered when people badmouth him and sometimes gets into a fight with them. He took part in illegal racing a few times and got arrested by the police once.

Comment: @windrider9268 I'm really sorry about your cousin! I hope he'll be OK! Based on your description, he's a kind of problem child and troublemaker. I wouldn't say that he's a mischief-maker because mischief is playful misbehavior.

Comment: @Enguroo thank you, I hope he'll eventually grow up. I think I'll go with "problem child".

Comment: @windrider9268 don't forget that if you say that someone is a problem child, you are somewhat obligated to care for them or help them. It's the shade of meaning to bear in mind.

Answer (score 1):

[**Juvenile Delinquent**](https://criminal.findlaw.com/juvenile-justice/juvenile-delinquents.html)

> Even kids can run afoul of the law. Once this happens, and a child enters the criminal justice system, he or she may be deemed a “juvenile delinquent.”
>   Juvenile delinquents are minors, usually defined as being between the ages of 10 and 18, who have committed some act that violates the law. These acts aren't called “crimes” as they would be for adults. Rather, crimes committed by minors are called “delinquent acts.”

Answer (score 1):

**[Tearaway](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tearaway)**

> [noun] A person who behaves in a wild or reckless manner.
>
> *‘some young tearaways set fire to the house’*

Answer (score 0):

**hellion**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/hellion)

> A mischievous, troublesome, or unruly person.
>   informal US a rough or rowdy person, esp a child; troublemaker.